# Where is the result of the smart contract call stored when using web3.py's transact method?

Tags: transactions, web3.py

I am using web3.py and trying to get the return value of a smart contract method after calling it. Of course, I can do it like this:

```
value = smart_contract_instance.someFunction()
```

but this does not give me any information about how much gas was used. If I use the `transact` method like this:

```
tx_hash = smart_contract_instance.transact({'to': w3.eth.accounts[0]}).someFunction()
```

I can access the receipt with `w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)`, but this does not give me the result. How can I access the result of the call without having to invoke the smart contract twice (as in using both code snippets from above)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transactions don't have return values. If the function you're calling returns a value, that's simply ignored. The typical pattern is to log an event from the function and look for that event in the transaction receipt.

Note that if you *call* a function without sending a transaction (probably what's happening in your first code snippet), then you do get a return value, but the call has no side effects (no state changes or ether transfers).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at the event documentation of web3.py. Regarding calls: What happens when I call a function where the return value depends on the input? Is the code still executed, but the state changes discarded?

Comment: Yes, the code is executed locally on the node you're connected to, and then the side effects are discarded.